# "impl requires a base type" for array-like type in Rust

Tags: rust

I defined a type as an array with fixed size and I try to implement some custom methods for it.

```
type Vec3 = [f64; 3];

impl Vec3 {
    fn display(&self) {
        println!("x = {}, y = {}, z = {}", self[0], self[1], self[2]);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0118]: no base type found for inherent implementation
 --> src/main.rs:7:6
  |
7 | impl Vec3 {
  |      ^^^^ impl requires a base type
  |
  = note: either implement a trait on it or create a newtype to wrap it instead

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What is the nature of this error and how do I fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
type Vec3 = [f64; 3];
```

doesn't really declare a new type, it merely declares a [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#creating-type-synonyms-with-type-aliases) called `Vec3` for an array `[f64; 3]`.

When we run `rustc --explain E0118`, the Rust compiler helpfully describes it for us:

```
You're trying to write an inherent implementation for something which isn't a
struct nor an enum.
```

So, you can only use `impl` for a `struct` or an `enum`. A quick fix in your case is to declare `Vec3` as a [tuple Struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types):

```
struct Vec3([f64; 3]);
```

But then that means rewriting your `display` method somewhat. For clarity, we'll destructure to a local variable:

```
    let Self(vec) = self;
    println!("x = {}, y = {}, z = {}", vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]);
```

You can see a working example on the [Playground (43122f5fdbd157b9925a5fd2f660c329)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43122f5fdbd157b9925a5fd2f660c329).